# Date pattern issue while parsing data with Bindy

Tags: java, jpa, apache-camel

I am reading a date value from the CSV file and the value is '21/08/2009'.
Bindy is giving me a error while parsing this data as follows:

**org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.format.FormatException: Date provided does not fit the pattern defined.**

I have written the following code .

```
package com.project1.projectdomain;

import java.lang.String;
import java.util.Date;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.CsvRecord;
import org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.annotation.DataField;

import com.project.Identifiable;

@Entity
@CsvRecord(separator = ",")
public class Trade implements Identifiable<String> {
     Classname classobject;

    @Id
    @DataField(pos = 1)
    private String id;

    @DataField(pos=2)
    private String code;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @DataField(pos=3)
    private Date date1;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@DataField(pos=4)
    private Date date2;
```

I use maven for building the project ,jpa 3.0 and apache camel.

Comment: What does your data look like? More context on the error (stacktrace) might help for a quick response too

Comment: It gives an error on while parsing the date field I have specified above.It is interesting that while reading this field from the CSV it is not able to parse it as a Date field.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cannot find the required formatter for the type java.sql.Date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220494/cannot-find-the-required-formatter-for-the-type-java-sql-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a [pattern attribute](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.9.0/camel-bindy/apidocs/org/apache/camel/dataformat/bindy/annotation/DataField.html#pattern%28%29) you need to set on [@DataField](http://camel.apache.org/maven/camel-2.9.0/camel-bindy/apidocs/org/apache/camel/dataformat/bindy/annotation/DataField.html) and specify the Date pattern you use according to [DateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html):

```
@DataField(pos=4, pattern="dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Comment: Hi Claus, I really appreciate your prompt replies.I changed the java.util.date to java.sql.Date.Then I did specify the pattern as follows                                 @DataField(pos=3,pattern="dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date tradeDate;                                       However, it is giving me the error as: Can not find a suitable formatter for the type: java.sql.Date.How do I fix this?

Comment: I got a weird solution for this problem.I right clicked the csv file and changed the date from "21/08/2009" to "21-08-2009. It worked.It parsed it correctly.How do I parse the date of the pattern "dd/MM/yyyy" Thank you Claus.

Comment: You should use java.util.Date